# ngAnimate not adding ng-enter classes in Ionic V1 app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-animate

I have an ionic v1 app. I want to add a basic animation to an element when it gets added to the view via `ng-repeat`. Reading the docs, the element should have a `ng-enter` class I can use to add CSS animations but it doesn't.

`ngAnimate` is included with Ionic. I'm loading the module:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ionic',
    'ngAnimate',
```

Here's view code which uses `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="entry" ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'-id'">{{message}}
</div>
```

When I dynamically add a message to `$scope.messages` it gets added to the view as you would expect but it does not contain the `ng-enter` class which according to the docs it should.

I'm using ionic version `1.3.3`, Angular `1.5.3` and ngAnimate `1.5.3`.

Here's a codepen showing the issue: https://codepen.io/jamesjacobs/pen/YQyaZq

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use ngAnimate with ionic

in **view**

```
<ion-item class="chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ...
```

**css**

If you want to use it with `chat-item` class use it as below

```
.chat-item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s;
}
```

above code will animate whole list at a once. If you want to animate each item one by one use `ng-enter-stagger` with delay 200ms

```
.chat-item.ng-enter-stagger {
  -webkit-animation-delay:200ms;
  animation-delay:200ms;

  /* override to make sure it's not inherited from other styles */
  -webkit-animation-duration:0;
  animation-duration:0;
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you aren't addressing my issue, the ngAnimate classes are not been applied to my elements. Elements that should have `ng-enter` for example, do not.